Wake up Windows by pressing any key
I have a Dell Latitude 7490 laptop running Windows 11 Pro. I want to be able to wake it up from sleep by pressing any key. At present, to wake it up, I have to open the lid and then press the power button. This doesn't suit me, because I've got a number of laptops (each with a different OS) stacked on top of it. It is unwieldy to have to lift up a number of laptops to open the lid of this one and press the power button. How to I enable wakeup by pressing any key on a USB keyboard?

I fixed this issue as follows:

Run Device Manager and expand Human Interface Devices

Select every device in turn.

If that device has a Power Management tab, and "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" is not enabled:

then enable "Allow this device to wake the computer".




I don't think your problem comes from the key not waking up from sleep. Pressing any key on any Windows machine should wake up your machine.
I think the problem is the action set up when closing the lid of your computer. You can access those setting here Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\System Settings.
I'm guessing the action when closing the lid is set to Hibernate and not Sleep.

Thanks, but I know it is sleep and not hibernate, because I put the laptop to sleep by using the menu Settings -> Power -> Sleep. After that, it doesn't wake up by pressing any key; only by pressing the Power button.

@k314159 have you tried checking your bios settings? Settings\Advanced\Wake Up Event Setup

Good idea, I'll take a look at that shortly.

Unfortunately that option doesn't seem to exist on the Dell Latitude 7490's BIOS settings. The only wake-up-related settings seem to be "USB Wake Support" and "Wake on LAN". I've enabled them but they don't make any difference, even when I plug in a USB keyboard again.
